# How to get serialized API view data into another view?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

What is the best way to get `DRF API` view data into another Django view?

Currently I am just calling the view through `requests` module:

```
response = requests.get('my_api_view')
```

but is there a cleaner way?

I can also just instantiate the API view class in another view, but this will give me unserialized objects.

Comment: Are you using python 3 or 2. Also what version of Django are you using?

Comment: Python 3 , Django 2.0

Comment: Are you using pagination ? Did you checked `get_paginated_response()` ?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by getting unserialized objects. You can do the following if you're using function-based views:

```
def view(request):
    # some stuff done
    return Response(<result>)

def another_view(request)
    return view(request)
```

If you're views are class based then you can do the following:

```
class AClassBasedView(SomeMixin, SomeOtherMixin):

    def get(self, request):
        # do something with the request
        return Response(<some result>)


class AnotherClassBasedView(SomeMixin, SomeOtherMixin):

    def compute_context(self, request, username):
        #some stuff here here                        
        return AnotherClassBasedView.as_view()(request)
```

Both of these will return a `<class 'rest_framework.response.Response'>` object which can be passed further.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly you want to achieve but wanting to call a view from another view maybe a sign of bad architecture. It could mean that you have a business logic implemented in the second view which you want to access in the first. Usually the rule of thumb is to move such a common logic somewhere else so it could be used by different views.
Again I don't know what you want to achieve but this is a possibilty.

Comment: $scholars: the reason for such design is that I want the normal view to render HTML template with data requested from the API view.

Comment: then you can easily move the logic inside the API view to another place. And if I may ask, if the input and output don't require the REST endpoint, why don't you implement the view in the Django view instead of using API view?

Comment: Ideally, sending a request to another view should only happen if it is in another service running in another server. Else it will duplicate all the checks for permission, authentication and other things that could be preventing by just calling it directly from python

Comment: $scholars: thanks for all your comments. I want to keep the API view, because once I pass the initial data to the template from normal view, the AJAX in the template will call the API view for filtered data whenever user interacts with sliders, dropdowns etc.

Comment: It's not really a must to entirely remove the API View. You can just move the common logic. If you can post your template view and API view, I can advise on how to separate the logic so that you can call it directly from Python